# How to extract and flatten a JSON array as well as specify an Array Value for 'TIMESTAMP BY' in Stream Analytics Query

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I got the following input stream data to Stream Analytics.

```
[
    {
        "timestamp": 1559529369274,
        "values": [
            {
                "id": "SimCh01.Device01.Ramp1",
                "v": 39,
                "q": 1,
                "t": 1559529359833
            },
            {
                "id": "SimCh01.Device01.Ramp2",
                "v": 183.5,
                "q": 1,
                "t": 1559529359833
            }
        ],
        "EventProcessedUtcTime": "2019-06-03T02:37:29.5824231Z",
        "PartitionId": 3,
        "EventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2019-06-03T02:37:29.4390000Z",
        "IoTHub": {
            "MessageId": null,
            "CorrelationId": null,
            "ConnectionDeviceId": "ew-IoT-01-KepServer",
            "ConnectionDeviceGenerationId": "636948080712635859",
            "EnqueuedTime": "2019-06-03T02:37:29.4260000Z",
            "StreamId": null
        }
    }
]
```

I try to extract the "values" array and specify the "t" within the array element for TIMESTAMP BY

I was able to query with simple SAQL statement within Stream Analytics to read the input and route to the output.  However, I only interested in the "values" array above.

This is my first attempt. It does not like my 'TIMESTAMP BY' statement when I try to re-start Stream Analytics Job

```
SELECT
    KepValues.ArrayValue.id,
    KepValues.ArrayValue.v,
    KepValues.ArrayValue.q,
    KepValues.ArrayValue.t
INTO
    [PowerBI-DS]
FROM
   [IoTHub-Input] as event
    CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(event.[values]) as KepValues
    TIMESTAMP BY KepValues.ArrayValue.t
```

==============================================================================
This is my 2nd attempt. It still does not like my 'TIMESTAMP BY' statement.

```
With [PowerBI-Modified-DS] As (
    SELECT
        KepValues.ArrayValue.id as ID,
        KepValues.ArrayValue.v as V,
        KepValues.ArrayValue.q as Q,
        KepValues.ArrayValue.t as T
    FROM
       [IoTHub-Input] as event
       CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(event.[values]) as KepValues
)
SELECT
    ID, V, Q, T
INTO
    [PowerBI-DS]
FROM 
    [PowerBI-Modified-DS] TIMESTAMP BY T
```

After extraction, this is what I expected, a table with columns "id", "v", "q", "t" and each row will have a single ArrayElement.  e.g.,

```
"SimCh01.Device01.Ramp1", 39, 1, 1559529359833
"SimCh01.Device01.Ramp2", 183.5, 1, 1559529359833
```

---

## Added

Since then,  I have modified the query as below to create a DateTime by converting the Unix time t into DateTime time

```
With [PowerBI-Modified-DS] As (
SELECT
        arrayElement.ArrayValue.id as ID,
        arrayElement.ArrayValue.v as V,
        arrayElement.ArrayValue.q as Q,
        arrayElement.ArrayValue.t as TT
FROM
       [IoTHub-Input] as iothubAlias
       CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(iothubAlias.data) as arrayElement 
)      
SELECT
    ID, V, Q, DATEADD(millisecond, TT, '1970-01-01T00:00:00Z')  as T
INTO
    [SAJ-01-PowerBI]
FROM 
    [PowerBI-Modified-DS]
```

I manage to add DATEADD() to convert Unix Time into DateTime and call it as T. Now how can I add 'TIMESTAMP BY'.  I did try to add behind [PowerBI-Modified-DS] . But the editor complains the insert is invalid.   What else can I do.  Or this is the best I can do.  I understand I need to set 'TIMESTAMP BY' so Power BI understand this is the streaming data.

Comment: Jay, thanks for format the JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

The [TIMESTAMP BY clause in Stream Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/timestamp-by-azure-stream-analytics?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstream-analytics%2FTOC.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json) requires a value to be of type DATETIME. String values conforming to ISO 8601 formats are supported. In your example, the value of 't' does not conform to this standard.

To use TIMESTAMP BY clause in your case, you will have to pre-process the data before sending it to Stream Analytics or change the source to create the event (specifically the field 't') using this format.

Stream Analytics assigns TIMESTAMP before the query is executed. So TIMESTAMP BY expression can only refer to fields in the input payload. You have 2 options.

1. You can have 2 ASA jobs. First does the CROSS APPLY and the 2nd job does TIMESTAMP BY.
2. You can implement a deserializer in C# ([sign up for preview access](https://aka.ms/asapreview1)). This way you can have one job that uses your implementation to read incoming events. Your deserializer will convert the unix time to DateTime and this field can then be used in your TIMESTAMP BY clause.

Comment: 'change the source to create the event (specifically the field 't') using this format.' Not sure what is this mean and what is the format.   I manage to use DATEADD to transform a Unix Time into DateTime.  But I am uncertain how to add 'TIMESTAMP BY' into the query.  Please have a look at the Added section in the question. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "using TIMESTAMP BY so PBI understands this is streaming data"? TIMESTAMP BY should be used if you want to process incoming events by event time and not arrival time. Even if you don't use this clause, ASA will still write to PBI streaming dataset but process events by arrival time. More details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/event-ordering

Comment: Sid,  I need to use the event time, that is why I somehow need to be able to use TIMESTAMP BY', But I am not sure how I can add 'TIMESTAMP BY' after I flattened the data into
"SimCh01.Device01.Ramp1", 39, 1,  '2019-01-01T00:00:00Z

Comment: @snwo339 - I edited my answer to address your comment above. Hope it helps.